# UIPageControl with scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i have to use two pages using UIPage Control.

Now my question Is there any need to use UIScrollView to use page controll?

Comment: No, you don't need to use `UIScrollView` as you manage `UIPageControl` by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scrollview and the page control are two separate components. When you scroll the scrollview, you need to change the status of the page control. The page control is just the series of dots.

If you want an easy way to integrate multiple view with page control in a scroll view, you can use [GCPagedScrollView](https://github.com/gcamp/GCPagedScrollView) that will ease this process and make a lot of things automatically.